# Error Correcting Code Generator Circuit Implementation with XOR gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, error-correction

I am supposed to implement the logic circuit of an ECC Generator. The circuit itself has 8 Data bits (D1-D8) as inputs and as outputs it generates a 13-bit vector, which is the hamming code (with parity bits P0-P4) that protect the Data bits.

Therefore, we have:

`P1 P2 D1 P3 D2 D3 D4 P4 D5 D6 D7 D8`

P1 = XOR(3 5 7 9 11)

How would I implement P1 in a circuit with XOR gates to begin with?

If I feed inputs 3 5 7 9 11 into a XOR gate, will it indeed give me the result of the parity bit 1 (P1)?

This is the schema of the ECC Generator:

[image]

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Yes, "XOR(a, b, c, d)" indicates an XOR gate with 4 inputs. If your xor gates have fewer inputs you should work out how to combine them to make an equivalent to a 5-input XOR. Hint: it's very simple to do.

Comment: How is it possible to have inputs 9 and 11, when `D` has a range from 1 to 8? The term `XOR(3 5 7 9 11)` is not valid. a) `3` does not indicate it's `D3`. b) If `XOR` is a 5-input function, each input value should be delimited by `,`.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite open ended but ECC was fun to explain to my other friends back in college so where we go. Firstly, a correction: This produces a **12bit number**, not a 13bit one. Data bits 0-7 and parity bits 0-3. Your schematic is wrong and would never work.

"If I feed inputs 3 5 7 9 11 into an XOR gate, will it indeed give me the result of the parity bit 1 (P1)?" Yes. That xor gate must have 5 inputs but yes. Also you shouldn't feed the outputs 3,5,7,9,11 of your circuit to the input so please refer to the equation as P1= D0 XOR D1 XOR D3 XOR D4 XOR D6.

If you don't have an XOR gate with 5 inputs then you'll need to ask a new question telling us what you actually have to work with.

Comment: While the original Hamming code for an 8 bit number produces a 12 bit code, many people prefer SECDED which, for an 8 bit number, requires a 13 bit code, such as an [extended Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Hamming_codes_with_additional_parity_.28SECDED.29). The schematic looks fine to me.